# How to copy workitem tree using API in azure devops

Tags: azure, api, rest, azure-devops, postman

How to copy workitem tree using API in azure devops ?
I need to copy workitems in azure devops by using API

I need to copy workitem tree ( child and sub child) for example, Feature with userstories and tasks
entire workitem tree need to copy
Is there any other method to copy workitem without API also fine.

Answer (score 0):

Currently I don't find a rest api that can implement your idea. Maybe using API to get all of the information of workitems and relationship and then create the workitems. In addition, in [Sprint 172 Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2020/sprint-172-update#copy-work-item-to-copy-children),  you can copy work item to copy children. But This feature isn't recursive. The sub child need to be copied manually.

Comment: Can you please copy  workitem API

Comment: For your  reference:  API [Work Items - Get Work Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/get-work-item?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP) . Parameter: $expand=all.

Comment: this is only single work item create but i want to copy complete workitem tree so is there any API for that

Comment: As I said in my answer, there is no single api that fits your requirements. Work Items - Get Work Item provides the links of parent and child. You need to find out the sub child manually via link.

Comment: Please share the API for get work items with parent, child and sub child and One api for create  workitems by using this get info